# Need help on understanding Heine-Borel property.

Tags: real-analysis

Heine-Borel Theorem states that if a set has an open cover and if we can find a finite subcover from that open cover that covers the set, the set would be compact. 
I got this question while I was trying to prove that Heine-Borel property will imply that the set is closed.

Is there any restriction on open sets that are the contained in the open cover? If not, can't I just make one of the open sets to be a set of real numbers? Then, the set would always have a finite subcover, that is, the set of all real numbers that covers the set. Hence, it can cover $(0,1)$ or any other open intervals but still $(0,1)$ is not closed.

Comment: All sets have some finite open cover. What you want is that all arbitrary open covers have some finite subcover.

Comment: "Heine-Borel Theorem states that if a set has an open cover and if we can find a finite subcover from that open cover that covers the set, the set would be compact. "  Absolutely not!  It says that if *EVERY* open cover (not just one open cover) has a finite subcover the set will be compact (but not by the theorem but by the definition) and that such a set is closed and bounded (and vice versa).

Comment: "Is there any restriction on open sets that are the contained in the open cover?"  Not "the" open cover.  **ANY** open cover.  So no restriction.  " If not, can't I just make one of the open sets to be a set of real numbers?"  Yes, that would be **one** open cover and it does have a finite subcover.  Now show that **EVERY** other open covers including the ones that do *not* have all the reals as a set *also* have a finite subcover.  If you can do *that* then yes (0,1) is closed.  (Does {(1/n, 1)} have a finite subcover?  It *must* if (0,1) is closed. And it doesn't.  So (0,1) is not closed

Comment: @fleablood Thank you so much for the clarification, now I understand it better. My book's definition was not very specific about it. I guess the author tried to make open cover arbitrary by saying $an open cover$ but I couldn't catch the intention.

Comment: I'm not saying that there aren't bad books out there, but... read it again.  I think you are misinterpretting the statement or the context in which it was stated.  It would be correct to say.  "S is compact if when S has an open cover, the cover has a finite subcover".  That means whichever open cover we pick will have a finite subcover, not that "S is compact if it has an open cover that has a finite subcover"  Those two statements are very different.

Comment: @fleablood Actually, the book says the set is compact if the set has an open cover, there exists finite subcover. So, I think it was giving the precise definition... thank you.

Comment: Yeah.  That's badly worded.  But it is correct.  If it has *a* cover, it could be any cover, and if that one cover most have a finite subcover, no matter which cover it is, then that's the same as saying every cover...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Heine Borel Theorem states that in $\mathbb{R}^n$, a set is compact iff it is closed and bounded. Perhaps in your class you initially defined compactness as being closed and bounded, but in general a set $K$ is compact if **every** open cover has a finite sub-cover.

An open cover $\mathcal{U}$ for as set $K$ is a collected of sets that are open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$K\subset\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{U}}U.$$ So, the sets simply must be open. I think the key point you are missing here is that all open covers have to have a finite subcover, not just some open cover. Otherwise, every subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ would be compact, because $\mathcal{U}=\{\mathbb{R}^n\}$ is an open cover for every subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

To see that every compact set is closed, suppose $K$ is compact and $p\not\in K$. For each $x\in K$, let $U_x$ be an open set containing $x$ but not $p$ (note that for every $x \in K$ we can always find a neighborhood $U_x$ of it such that it does not contain $p$ even if $p$ is a limit point of $K$), and $V_x$ be an open set containing $p$ such that $U_x\cap V_x=\emptyset$. Then $\mathcal{U}=\{U_x:x\in K\}$ is an open cover of $K$. Thus, we can extract a finite subcover $\{U_{x_1},\dots, U_{x_n}\}$. Note that $$\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n V_{x_i}\right)\cap\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n U_{x_i}\right)=\emptyset$$ by our construction. Since $K\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_{x_i}$, it follows that $V=\bigcap_{i=1}^n V_{x_i}$ is an open set containing $p$ that contains no element of $K$. Thus, $p$ cannot be a limit point of $K$. It follows that $K$ contains all of its limit points, and is closed.

Note that the point where we used a **finite** subcover is so that we could take a finite intersection of open sets to ensure $V$ was open.

Comment: So $V$ only contains $p$ as its element? Does this also contradict that $V$ has to be an open set because singleton cannot be an open set?

Comment: No, each $V_{x_i}$ was on open set containing $p$ which was disjoint from $U_{x_i}$. As a finite intersection of open sets, $V$ is open, so contains infinitely many points. Its just that none of these points are in $K$, because we showed $V$ and $K$ are disjoint.

Comment: Is this the only way of proving the compact set is closed? I don't think I would have come up with this proof even if I spent a month on trying.

Comment: This is in sense some the most general way of doing it, since it works in a large class of topological spaces (Hausdorff spaces, which are spaces where for any $x\neq y$ you can find disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ containing $x$ and $y$ respectively).


In $\mathbb{R}^n$ (and in fact any metric space), sequential compactness is equivalent to compactness. A set $K$ is sequentially compact if every sequence in $K$ has a convergent subsequence with a limit in $K$. It is perhaps easier to show $K$ is closed using this characterization.

Comment: As for coming up with this proof yourself, this is perhaps the type of proof that you may need to see other proofs that use this idea of disjoint neighborhoods to come up with this idea. It's okay if you couldn't come up with it on first try. What's important is that you understand the idea of the proof and could reproduce on your own now (or maybe in a few days to make sure you actually understand). And perhaps most important is that you could apply the same idea to other proofs now.

Comment: Does it mean I have to prove Bolzano-Weistrass Theorem is satisfied by the compact set? This was actually one of the problems I had to do. That compact, Heine-Borel property, and Bolzano-Weistrass theorem all imply each other.

Comment: As I pointed out in my post, the key idea here was we wanted to construct an open set containing $p$ that was disjoint from $K$ (so we could show it is not a limit point). To do this, we took advantage of the fact that finite intersections of open sets are open.

Comment: Yes, you would need to prove Bolzano Weierstrass to show that sequential compactness is equivalent to compactness.

Comment: I'm sorry but does $V_x$ depend on $x\in E$? Why was it necessary to to come up with multiple sets of $V_x's$? Is there any correlation between $U_x$ and $V_x$? I am having this question because I was trying to prove this by proving the set $E^c$ is open. For this method, I made an open cover of open balls around each $x\in E$ and extract the subcover of finitely many open balls for some $x_1, \dots, x_n \in E$. But this method restricts the radius of those open balls to be $\frac{1}{2}\|x-p\|$, where $p\in E^c$.

Comment: This proof claims that $\cap_{i=1}^{n}B_\delta(x_i,p)$ will become the smallest open ball around $p$ and this ball will not contain any $x\in E$. I am having hard time understanding why this is so. I understand that $\cap_{i=1}^{n}B_\delta(x_i,p)$ is the smallest open ball of the open balls. But how can I explain this implies this smallest open ball will not contain any element in $E$?

Comment: For your first question, for every $x\in E$, we took an open set around $x$ which we called $U_x$ and an open set around $p$ which we called $V_x$ such that $U_x$ and $V_x$ are disjoint. Thus, $V_x$ depends on $x$ because it depends on $U_x$. An example construction of this is similar to what you mention, let $r=\frac{1}{2}||x-p||$, and $U_x=B_r(x)$ and $V_x=B_r(p)$. Now, in fact the set $V$ mentioned in my proof is an open set containing $p$ which is contained in $E^c$, so we could have alternatively just started that we have shown $E^c$ is open.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by $B_\delta(x_i,p)$. Could you explain this notation? But using the language of the proof, each $U_{x_i}$ and $V_{x_i}$ pair is disjoint. This tells us that $V=\cap_{i=1}^n V_{x_i}$ is disjoint from all of the $U_{x_i}$. Thus, $V$ is also disjoint from the union of the $U_{x_i}$, which contains $E$. Thus, $V$ is disjoint from $E$.

Answer (score 3):

That is not what the Heine-Borel Theorem states. The Heine-Borel Theorem states that if $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ (with the usual topology/metric), then $S$ is compact if and only if $S$ is closed and bounded.

What you stated is more like the definition of compact: $S$ is compact provided that for *every* open cover of $S$, there is a finite subcover. That "every" is extremely important. Sure, $\{(0,1)\}$ is an open cover of $(0,1)$ and it has a finite subcover, but there exist open covers of $(1,2)$ with no finite subcover. Thus $(0,1)$ is not compact.

Comment: This is repeated in several different answers here, so picking yours out is a little unfair, but I don't want to repeat the comment for everyone. In the OP's case, I would guess that the book - which is clearly an intro real analysis book - is only concerned with $\Bbb R$ and defines compact as "closed and bounded". Under that definition, the content of the H-B theorem is indeed "every cover has a finite subcover if and only if the set is compact".

Comment: Thanks, that is a good point which I had not considered.

Answer (score 3):

"Heine-Borel Theorem states that if a set has an open cover and if we can find a finite subcover from that open cover that covers the set, the set would be compact."

1) that's not the theorem that states that but the definition of compact and

2) *VERY IMPORTANT*  It's not that if you can fine *one* open cover with a finite subcover.  It's that ***EVERY*** open cover must have a finite subcover.

So, yes, $\{\mathbb R\}$ is an open cover of $(0,1)$ and $\{\mathbb R\}$ is itself finite.  That is true$*$.

But $\{\mathbb R\}$ is only *one* open cover.  There are others.  And all the others must *also* have finite subcovers for $(0,1)$ to be compact.

$\{(\frac 1n, 1)| n \in \mathbb N\}$ is a different open cover.  It does *not* have a finite subcover.  So it is a counter example that proves that not *every* open cover of $(0,1)$ has a finite subcover.

So $(0,1)$ is not compact.  And by the Heine-Borel Theorem is not closed and bounded.

=====

$*$[  $\{\mathbb R\}$ is an open cover for *every* subset of $\mathbb R$ which means every set is compact which means every set is closed and bounded which ... not only is obviously not true, would make the word "compact" utterly useless.  Also "closed" and "bounded" would be meaningless.]

Comment: Regarding 1, it can, depending on your definition, very well be a theorem. It most likely is one in first semester mathematics.

Comment: yes, you can have boring covers such as open covers that cover the entire interval but then you can also construct infinitely large covers. The definition of compactness requires that EVERY open cover has a finite subcover

Answer (score 2):

It has to work for any open cover rather than just a particular open cover.

For exampl, consider the open cover $\{\left( \frac1{N}, 1 \right):N \geq 1\}$, finitely many of them will not cover $(0,1)$.